# What's the default value of a declared objects array?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
Obj[] array = new Obj[10];
```

What's the default value for each object in this array?
I want them all to be null and I'm not sure if there's a need to set each of them to null in a loop.

Comment: `array = {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null};`

Comment: `Obj[] array = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => YourDefaultValue).ToArray();` if you want your own default value(s)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [the online documentation says so](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx):

> The default values of numeric array elements are set to zero, and reference elements are set to null.

The [C# specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029) (Section 1.8 Arrays) is even more specific:

> The `new` operator automatically initializes the elements of an array to their default value, which, for example, is zero for all numeric types and null for all reference types.

Answer (score 1):

This highly depends on the type of object `Obj` is. If it is a reference type then the values are `null`. If it is a value type then the value is `not null`.

More general the values of the array are initialized to the value returned by `default(ObjClass)` respectivly `default(ObjStruct)` or generally `default(anyTypeHere)`

## Example

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ObjStruct[] array = new ObjStruct[10];
        Console.WriteLine(array[0].Test);
    
        ObjClass[] array = new ObjClass[10];
        Console.WriteLine(array[0].Test); //NullReferenceException
    }
}

public class ObjClass
{
    public string Test { get { return "Not null"; } }
}

public struct ObjStruct
{
    public string Test { get { return "Not null"; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each array element is initialized with default value of the type `default(T)`.

If it is a reference type then is `null`, if it is a value type then is 0 for types like `int`, `long`, `double`, and in the case of `struct` fields are initialized to their default values.

Answer (score 0):

by default it will be null.
you can see more explanation here if you will use extended types
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx